# Geração de Logs com NLog?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, log

Estou usando o *NLog*, e para cada cliente logado no sistema eu gostaria de criar um comportamento para a geração de logs da seguinte forma:

```
[nome-cliente-1]-[dataAtual].txt

[nome-cliente-2]-[dataAtual].txt

Ex: Joao-da-silva-01-11-2016.txt
```

Gostaria que as informações fossem escritas no arquivo gerado somente no dia. 
Caso chegasse à meia noite criaria
outro arquivo, de modo que exista um arquivo por dia para cada cliente.

- É possível fazer isso?

Procurei por tutoriais mas não encontrei nada parecido.

Comment: Sobre a questão do 'por dia' de uma olhada [nesta página do wiki](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target) do nlog, na parte 'Time-based file archival'. Infelizmente é em inglês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael,

Segue como eu fiz com o NLOG, instalar os packages via nuget:

```
Install-Package NLog
Install-Package NLog.Config
```

No NLog.config incluir ao targets o trecho abaixo:

```
  <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}-${environment:variable=CLIENT_NAME}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
```

Para logar o erro da forma que você quer: cliente e data atual no arquivo no 'fileName', é só seguir o padrão para o que você precisa.

```
        NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        try
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENT_NAME", "Cliente 001");
            throw new Exception("Cliente 001 error");           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e.Message);
        }
```

A data que a variavel {shortdate} cria neste formato "2016-11-03", se for necessário, criar outra variável de ambiente para o seu contexto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Rodrigo! Fiz dessa forma mas não gerou a pasta com o arquivo, você têm ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Raphael, de acordo com o fileName, será criada uma pasta chamada logs dentro do local do executável da aplicação, (em nosso cenário será criado dentro da pasta Bin) com o arquivo chamado 2016-11-03-Cliente 001.txt.

Certeza que não gerou nenhum arquivo de log?

Comment: Sim, nenhum arquivo :( Estranho porque fiz as configurações sem nenhum problema. Vou dar uma verificada.

Comment: Raphael, segue o repositório para você testar: https://github.com/rodrigoacr/NLogExample

Comment: Ah, achei! O "writeTo" não estava apontando para o name do target.
Muito obrigado mesmo Rodrigo! Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

No arquivo NLog.Config eu configuro o file name desta forma

```
 fileName="/erros/${date:format=yyyy\MM}//${date:format=dd} - ${event-properties:item=name}.json">
```

e para logar faça da seguinte forma:

```
    Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Fatal, "", e.Message);
    theEvent.Properties["name"] = "Nome";
    log.Log(theEvent);
```